# Correctly building the Classifier model (Darknet19) of YOLOv2 in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to read a paper and build the classifier portion from scratch but I seem to be running into an error and not sure if I am building it correctly:

Here is the paper: 
https://pjreddie.com/media/files/papers/YOLO9000.pdf

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, concatenate
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization,GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.activations import softmax
from functools import partial

#First train body for image classification
#Then train head

new_conv = partial(Conv2D ,padding = "same")

def _base_block(out,x):
    "(3,3), Leaky, Batch"
    x =new_conv(out, (3,3))(x)
    x =LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x)
    x =BatchNormalization()(x) 
    return x

def _block_1(out, x):     
    """
    output follows:
    out//2, out

    """
    x =  new_conv(out//2, (1,1))(x)
    x =LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = _base_block(out,x)
    return x

def _block_2(out, x):    
    """
    output follows:
    out, out//2, out

    """  
    x =_base_block(out,x)
    x = _block_1(out, x)
    return x


def Darknet19():
    input_layer = Input((img_size, img_size, 3))
    x = _base_block(32,input_layer)
    x =  MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides = 2)(x)
    x = _base_block(64,x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides = 2)(x)
    x = _block_2(128, x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides = 2)(x)
    x = _block_2(256, x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides = 2)(x)
    x = _block_2(512, x)
    x = _block_1(512, x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides = 2)(x)
    x =_block_2(1024, x)
    x = _block_1(512, x)
    x = new_conv(1, (1,1), activation = "linear")(x)
    model = Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs = x)  
    return model

def Darknet_classifier():
    base_model = Darknet19()
    x = base_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    output = softmax(x)
    model = Model(inputs = base_model.inputs, outputs = output)

    return model

img_size = 426 #multiple of 30
model = Darknet19()
model =Darknet_classifier()
print(model.summary())
```

Error I am receiving:

> 'Found: ' + str(x))
>   ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("Softmax:0", shape=(?, 1), 
>   dtype=float32)

It seems I cannot go from GAP to softmax. Is my interpretation of the model incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't applying softmax correctly, you can use the `Activation` layer for this:

```
from keras.layers import Activation

output = Activation("softmax")(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of above error by using `Lambda` layer, which basically wraps arbitrary expressions as a `Layer` object.

Modify `Darknet_classifier` function in above code to something like below:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda

def apply_soft(x): 
    output = softmax(x)
    return output

def Darknet_classifier():
    base_model = Darknet19()
    x = base_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    output = Lambda(apply_soft)(x)
    model = Model(inputs = base_model.inputs, outputs = output)
    return model
```

Alternatively, replace `output = softmax(x)` with `output = Lambda(lambda x: softmax(x))(x)`

Comment: You shouldn't recommend to blindly switch from keras to tf.keras, it might introduce bugs and incompatibilities with the OPs codebase.

Comment: My bad. There was a bug in my code which I just corrected. Thanks for your valuable feedback.